# Deploying Flask app with multiple URL on Kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, flask, kubernetes

I'm starting with Kubernetes Docker and Flask, I need to publish a Flask app that contains several routes. How can I change the paths into my `deploy.yml` in order to access the multiple URLs.

Here is my `app.py` :

```
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def extract():
    {code}


@app.route('/secondeurl', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def seconde():
    {code}
```

And my deploy.yml :

```
paths:
  - path: /
    backend:
      serviceName: hello
      servicePort: 8080
```

I tried those different methods and none of them worked correctly :

```
paths:
- path: /.*
  backend:
    serviceName: hello
    servicePort: 8080


paths:
   - path: /
    backend:
     serviceName: hello
     servicePort: 8080
    - path: /secondeurl
    backend:
     serviceName: hello
     servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: It's really unclear to me what are you trying to achieve, please explain better your environment. What kind of Kubernetes are you running? it all is happening inside the cluster or there is something outside? is this paths an ingress object or are you trying to config it somewhere else? Please if possible post your whole deploy.yaml, redact what you need but will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
no need to define secondurl route on flask side.
"/" route enough to handle request, you should handle on ingress rules side .

 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      name: ingress-flask-dev
      namespace: default
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: first_domain
          http:
            paths:
            - path: /
              backend:
                serviceName: flask_app
                servicePort: 5000

        - host: second_domain
          http:
            paths:
            - path: /
              backend:
                serviceName: flask_app
                servicePort: 5000
```